# Angular FormControl value set to null inside service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a Reactive Angular form which takes mobile number and some other fields as inputs. Below is the code:

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="contactDetailsForm">
  <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'ngxIntlInputBorder'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
          [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="false" [searchCountryFlag]="true"
          [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
          [selectedCountryISO]="countryCode" [maxLength]="10" [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name"
          [phoneValidation]="false" aria-label="pMobileNo" formControlName="primaryMobile" id="phone"
          (focusout)="validatePrimaryMobile()"></ngx-intl-tel-input>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.serviceForm = this.registerService.getContactDetails();
    if(this.serviceForm!=null){
      this.contactDetailsForm = this.serviceForm;
      if(this.serviceForm.get('country').value != 91){
        this.indiaFlag = false;
      }
      return;
    }
    this.contactDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
      primaryMobile: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]),
    });
  }

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.registerService.holdContactDetails(this.contactDetailsForm);
  }
```

**component.service**

```
holdContactDetails(contactDetails:FormGroup){
    this.contactDetails=contactDetails;
    console.log('Hold: ', this.contactDetails);
    this.mobile = this.contactDetails.get('primaryMobile').value;
    console.log("Mobil obj: ", this.mobile);
  }

  getContactDetails():FormGroup{
    if(this.contactDetails!=null){
      console.log('this.mobile: ', this.mobile);
      this.contactDetails.controls.primaryMobile.value = this.mobile;
      console.log('get: ', this.contactDetails)
    }
    return this.contactDetails;
  }
```

When calling the `holdContactDetails()`, the value of formGroup is updated successfully and i can see the below value of `this.mobile` on console:

```
{number: "9958244118", internationalNumber: "+91 99582 44118", nationalNumber: "099582 44118", countryCode: "IN", dialCode: "+91"}
```

When calling the `getContactDetails()` function, the value of `this.mobile` is correctly printed inside the function but in the returned formGroup, the value for `primaryMobile` is null.
Below is the screenshot of the same:

[image: On call of holdContactDetails()]

[image: On call of getContactDetails()]

As you can see in the images, when holding, the value for mobile is an object and status is also valid. But on calling get function, the value is updated to null and statu to invalid. Why is this happening?

**Update**
I think I need to be more clear regarding my question. The question here is not how to set the form control value inside service. My question is **why** do I need to set the value of a form control explicitly when it is already set when I send the formGroup to the service.

Comment: If you want to update the value of  formControl  you should use  setValue or patchValue.

Comment: i am not trying to update the value of form control. my question is if the value is present when I am destroying the component, then why does it get updated to null when calling the get fn to fetch formgroup value

Comment: Since object are reference type it's setting formControl object value to null. once formControlDirective gets destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Reactive forms are sometimes confusing, the thing is you can not set a value to them using the assign operator (=)  and you need to use the two methods from Angular Formgroup: `setValue` and `patchValue`
The difference between these two is that setValue is for the whole formGroup no matter how many controllers that group has, but in the other hand, patchValue way easier to use. Example of using patchValue:

`this.contactDetails.get('primaryMobile').pathValue('123456789');`

you can learn more about reactive forms in Angular here:
https://link.medium.com/TRvHAhuzB7

Comment: i have updated the question. Do read the update part and tell me why do i have to explicitly set the value of primaryMobile when it is provided on component destruction